# Replace a XML File in a JAR File

Tags: java, xml, exception, file-not-found

Im am trying to replace a XML file while executing the JAR File. But Currently It comes with with an Java IO File not Found Exception. But i doubled Check the Path and it is correct. I am wondering if it is possible to replace a xml file within an jar file. If so how is it done. Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the classpath for the execution ?

Comment: You're trying to *replace* an XML file that is stored *inside* the very same JAR file that you're executing?

Answer (score 5):

yes you can do that. Make dir where you want to try the below commands. Go to that dir and try:

```
>cd <to_your_dir>
>jar -xvf <jar_file_path_with_name>
```

This will extract the jar out. Change the file that you want to change and jar it back:

```
>jar -cvf <out_jar_file_name> *
```

Make sure you are running this from with in the folder where you extracted the jar. you can verify the contents structure by running below command on both the jars:

```
>jar -tvf <jar_file_name>
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do it is this:

```
# Find the file inside the jar
jar tvf <JarFile> | grep xml | less

# Extract your file
jar xvf <JarFile> <FilePath> 

# Edit your file

# Replace updated file in your jar
jar uvf <JarFile> <UpdatedFileWithSameName>
```